# Ordering lexicographically

Tags: javascript

So I was trying to solve this question on stackoverflow

Question Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-data-in-log-files/

**Question:** 
Basically, we need to Reorder the logs so that all of the letter-logs come before any digit-log.  The letter-logs are ordered lexicographically ignoring identifier, with the identifier used in case of ties.  The digit-logs should be put in their original order.

For the question I wrote this also

```
/**
 * @param {string[]} logs
 * @return {string[]}
 */
var reorderLogFiles = function(logs) {
    const letterLogs = []
    const digitLogs = []
    let i = 0; 
    while (i<logs.length) {
        const logger = logs[i]
        const secondWordIndex = logger.indexOf(' ') + 1 
        console.log(logger[secondWordIndex])
        if (isNaN(logger[secondWordIndex])) letterLogs.push(logger)
        else digitLogs.push(logger)
        i++
    }

    return [...letterLogs, ...digitLogs]
};
```

but this isn't lexicographically ordered because I am not sure what does lexicographically ordering mean

this is the given input/output

```
Input: logs = ["dig1 8 1 5 1","let1 art can","dig2 3 6","let2 own kit dig","let3 art zero"]
Output: ["let1 art can","let3 art zero","let2 own kit dig","dig1 8 1 5 1","dig2 3 6"]
```

**Question:** Can someone help me in formulating algo for the above question? I tried doing `letterLogs.sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b))` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

**Wikipedia:**

> In mathematics, the lexicographic or lexicographical order (also known
>   as lexical order, dictionary order, alphabetical order or
>   lexicographic(al) product) is a generalization of the way words are
>   alphabetically ordered based on the alphabetical order of their
>   component letters. This generalization consists primarily in defining
>   a total order over the sequences (often called strings in computer
>   science) of elements of a finite totally ordered set, often called an
>   alphabet.

**Lexicographical order is alphabetical order preceded by a length comparison.**

That is to say, a string a is lexicographically smaller than a string b

- if the length of a is smaller than the length of b, or
- else they are of the same length and a is alphabetically smaller than b.

To put items in the order, there must be a way to compare two items. With strings, the usual order is Lexicographic Order
basically, its alphabetical order.

[lexicographical vs alphabetical-order](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-lexicographical-and-alphabetical-order)

**what you have to do from the question:**

In your question, you are supposed to **order** all **`let*...`** strings **before** dig*.... strings, and **among all** `let1*` strings they should be `lexicographically ordered` same with `dig*` strings.

Check the below **solution**:

**Notice in array `logs` I have added another element `"let0 art can"` so that ties scenario should occur.**

**Assumption:**

1. All strings will start either with "let" or "dig".

```js
/*
Basically, we need to Reorder the logs so that all of the letter-logs come before any digit-log. 

The letter-logs are ordered lexicographically ignoring identifiers, 

with the identifier used in case of ties.

The digit-logs should be put in their original order.


*/

let logs = ["dig1 8 1 5 1","let1 art can","let0 art can", "dig2 3 6","let2 own kit dig","let3 art zero"];

//Notice in array logs I have added another element "let0 art can" so that ties scenario should occure.

let letterLogs = logs.filter((log) => log.startsWith("let"));    //get all letter strings 

let digitLogs = logs.filter((log) => log.startsWith("dig"));   //get all digit strings


//custom sort function
let sortFun = function(a, b) {

   let sortResult =  (function removeIdentifiers(a, b){  //remove identifiers
      let aCopy = a.replace(/[0-9]*/gm, "").replace(/\s\s+/gm," ");   //remove digits from the string also replace more than one space with just single space
      let bCopy = b.replace(/[0-9]*/gm, "").replace(/\s\s+/gm," ");;  //remove digits from the string also replace more than one space with just single space
       
      let result = (function sortCopies(a, b){ //sort a and b with identifiers removed
        if(a > b)
          return 1;

        if(b > a)
          return -1;

        return 0;
      })(aCopy, bCopy);

      
      //if identifires removed sort result it 0, i.e. tie the sort with identifiers
      if(result == 0){
         if(a > b)
          return 1;

         if(b > a)
            return -1;

         return 0;
      } else {
        return result;
      }
      
   })(a, b);
   
   return sortResult;  //return the final sort result
   
}

sortedLetterLogs = letterLogs.sort(sortFun)

console.log("sortedLetterLogs", sortedLetterLogs);
/*
sortedLetterLogs [
  "let0 art can",
  "let1 art can",
  "let3 art zero",
  "let2 own kit dig"
]
*/

let finalResult = [...sortedLetterLogs, ...digitLogs ];

console.log("finalResult", finalResult);
/*
finalResult [
  "let0 art can",
  "let1 art can",
  "let3 art zero",
  "let2 own kit dig",
  "dig1 8 1 5 1",
  "dig2 3 6"
]
*/
```

Comment: Can you help me with a working code example please?

Comment: @anny123 check the solution, tell me if this helps.